# Pandas - json normalize inside dataframe

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe

I want to break down a column in a dataframe into multiple columns.

I have a dataframe with the following configuration:

```
    GroupId,SubGroups,Type,Name
    -4781505553015217258,"{'GroupId': -732592932641342965, 'SubGroups': [], 'Type': 'DefaultSite', 'Name': 'Default Site'}",OrganisationGroup,CompanyXYZ
    -4781505553015217258,"{'GroupId': 8123255835936628631, 'SubGroups': [], 'Type': 'SiteGroup', 'Name': 'MERCEDES BENZ'}",OrganisationGroup,CompanyXYZ
    -4781505553015217258,"{'GroupId': -1785570219922840611, 'SubGroups': [], 'Type': 'SiteGroup', 'Name': 'VOLVO'}",OrganisationGroup,CompanyXYZ
    -4781505553015217258,"{'GroupId': -3670461095557699088, 'SubGroups': [], 'Type': 'SiteGroup', 'Name': 'SCANIA'}",OrganisationGroup,CompanyXYZ
    -4781505553015217258,"{'GroupId': 8683757391859854416, 'SubGroups': [], 'Type': 'SiteGroup', 'Name': 'DRIVERS'}",OrganisationGroup,CompanyXYZ
    -4781505553015217258,"{'GroupId': -8066654520755643389, 'SubGroups': [], 'Type': 'SiteGroup', 'Name': 'X - DECOMMISSION'}",OrganisationGroup,CompanyXYZ
    -4781505553015217258,"{'GroupId': 4177323092254043025, 'SubGroups': [], 'Type': 'SiteGroup', 'Name': 'X-INSTALLATION'}",OrganisationGroup,CompanyXYZ
    -4781505553015217258,"{'GroupId': -6088426161802844604, 'SubGroups': [], 'Type': 'SiteGroup', 'Name': 'FORD'}",OrganisationGroup,CompanyXYZ
    -4781505553015217258,"{'GroupId': 8512440039365422841, 'SubGroups': [], 'Type': 'SiteGroup', 'Name': 'HEAVY VEHICLES'}",OrganisationGroup,CompanyXYZ
```

I want to create a new dataframe where the `SubGroups` column is broken into its components. Note that the names inside `SubGroups` column are prefixed with `SubGroups_`

```
GroupId, SubGroup_GroupId, SubGroup_SubGroups, SubGroup_Type, SubGroup_Name, Type, Name
-4781505553015217258, -732592932641342965, [], 'DefaultSite', 'Default Site', OrganisationGroup, CompanyXYZ
-4781505553015217258, 8123255835936628631, [], 'SiteGroup', 'MERCEDES BENZ', OrganisationGroup, CompanyXYZ
```

I have tried the following code:

```
for row in AllSubGroupsDF.itertuples():
    newDF= newDF.append((pd.io.json.json_normalize(row.SubGroups)))
```

But it returns

```
GroupId,SubGroups,Type,Name
-732592932641342965,[],DefaultSite,Default Site
8123255835936628631,[],SiteGroup,MERCEDES BENZ
-1785570219922840611,[],SiteGroup,VOLVO
-3670461095557699088,[],SiteGroup,SCANIA
8683757391859854416,[],SiteGroup,DRIVERS
-8066654520755643389,[],SiteGroup,X - DECOMMISSION
4177323092254043025,[],SiteGroup,X-INSTALLATION
-6088426161802844604,[],SiteGroup,FORD
8512440039365422841,[],SiteGroup,HEAVY VEHICLES
```

I would like to have it all end up in one dataframe but I'm not sure how. Please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `ast` package:-

```
import pandas as pd
import ast
data = [[-4781505553015217258,"{'GroupId': -732592932641342965, 'SubGroups': [], 'Type': 'DefaultSite', 'Name': 'Default Site'}","OrganisationGroup","CompanyXYZ"],
    [-4781505553015217258,"{'GroupId': 8123255835936628631, 'SubGroups': [], 'Type': 'SiteGroup', 'Name': 'MERCEDES BENZ'}","OrganisationGroup","CompanyXYZ"],
    [-4781505553015217258,"{'GroupId': -1785570219922840611, 'SubGroups': [], 'Type': 'SiteGroup', 'Name': 'VOLVO'}","OrganisationGroup","CompanyXYZ"],
    [-4781505553015217258,"{'GroupId': -3670461095557699088, 'SubGroups': [], 'Type': 'SiteGroup', 'Name': 'SCANIA'}","OrganisationGroup","CompanyXYZ"],
    [-4781505553015217258,"{'GroupId': 8683757391859854416, 'SubGroups': [], 'Type': 'SiteGroup', 'Name': 'DRIVERS'}","OrganisationGroup","CompanyXYZ"],
    [-4781505553015217258,"{'GroupId': -8066654520755643389, 'SubGroups': [], 'Type': 'SiteGroup', 'Name': 'X - DECOMMISSION'}","OrganisationGroup","CompanyXYZ"],
    [-4781505553015217258,"{'GroupId': 4177323092254043025, 'SubGroups': [], 'Type': 'SiteGroup', 'Name': 'X-INSTALLATION'}","OrganisationGroup","CompanyXYZ"],
    [-4781505553015217258,"{'GroupId': -6088426161802844604, 'SubGroups': [], 'Type': 'SiteGroup', 'Name': 'FORD'}","OrganisationGroup","CompanyXYZ"],
    [-4781505553015217258,"{'GroupId': 8512440039365422841, 'SubGroups': [], 'Type': 'SiteGroup', 'Name': 'HEAVY VEHICLES'}","OrganisationGroup","CompanyXYZ"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["GroupId","SubGroups","Type","Name"])
df["SubGroup_GroupId"] = df["SubGroups"].map(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x)["GroupId"])
df["SubGroup_SubGroups"] = df["SubGroups"].map(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x)["SubGroups"])
df["SubGroup_Type"] = df["SubGroups"].map(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x)["Type"])
df["SubGroup_Name"] = df["SubGroups"].map(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x)["Name"])
df
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hi Tuhin. Tks for the answer.

In my case I have to convert: 

ast.literal_eval(x)

to

ast.literal_eval(str(x))

and it works fine.

Tks again

Comment: Sure Tuhin. I did it